# knowing graphic card memory

Tags: nvidia

When I put `lspci | grep VGA` I got these

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 435M] (rev a1)
```

Is there any way to know more detail on them? For example My nVidia is 1GB is there any **command line** **which shows nvidia is 1GB?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ lspci -v -s 01:00.0
```

That should output the memory in Brackets after the usual output.

Comment: the first one is OK. But the second one hase no output

Comment: @alex Ok, I'll check that asap, removing it in the meanwhile